# Why url returns JSON data via browser but shows nothing with curl (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is true)?

Tags: php, curl, json

I want to get json data from here: [JSON url](http://cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/filtrar.json?page=1&order_by=media&status_id=7&posicao_id=);

Using Chrome I can see all JSON data, but using curl (below code) it seems to redirect and get lost (if CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is false, it does nothing):

```
$json_url = 'http://cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/filtrar.json?page=1&order_by=media&status_id=7&posicao_id=1';
            $ch = curl_init($json_url);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
            //curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false );
            //even killing the redirect process it does not return JSON data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            $data = curl_exec( $ch );
            $dataDecoded = json_decode($data);
            print_r($dataDecoded);
```

I saw something about simulating a browser with curl but I tought agent would do the trick. Maybe something about server using cookies... I really don't know. I saw other answers here today but they didn't solve my problem. Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: you're simply assuming curl succeeded. at minimum you should have `if ($data === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }` to handle that, then check that `$data` is **BEFORE** you try to decode it. if it's corrupted somehow, you'll just get another boolean false back.

Comment: if I open the JSON url in my browser I get redirected to http://sportv.globo.com/site/cartola-fc/. Are you sure this is the correct url ?

Comment: I've just opened it with Google Chrome and is showing JSON data. Try to put 1 at the end, still redirects?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong variable use:

```
        $data = curl_exec( $ch );
        ^^^^^--- data here
        $dataDecoded = json_decode($json);
                                    ^^^^--- not $data here
```

So you're trying to decode a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, the code that was running already had that correction, I've just forgot to put here. My mistake. Now the question code is corrected. The answer for my problem is using CURLOPT_SLL_VERIFYPEER. But thanks anyway!